# Error when trying to export iOS App Archive for AdHoc Deployment

Tags: xcode, push-notification, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I have two apps that I am building an AdHoc Archive for (for internal distribution, not using Apple's new TestFlight mechanism).

One works fine, the other creates the archive, but then throws an error when I try to export it into an IPA file for AdHoc deployment - the error says:

"None of the matching provisioning profiles include the devices: ..."

and it then lists all devices within my Developer account that are NOT selected on the AdHoc Provisioning File.

It's almost as if XCode requires me to have *all* devices on the profile, not just a selection.

As I said - the process works fine for one app, fails for the other, and the only difference is that I have 'Push Notifications' enabled for the one that fails, which results in the provisioning profile having this extra entry:

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
```

This used to work fine earlier ? Any ideas ? I'd like to be able to test apps that use push notifications with AdHoc deployed apps on select devices.

Answer (score 0):

The Push Notification entitlement wasn't the problem - it was the fact that the provisioning file for the app that wouldn't export was using an explicit App ID (a requirement for Push).

I created a new distribution profile using a wildcard App ID instead of a specific one, and now the app exports fine.

Still...not ideal if you want to test push notifications in an app but only for select devices.